# Format error when downloading Blob from React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, file, blob

I'm trying to download a Blob from React that can be either a PDF or an image(jpg, jpeg, png...). PDF's are downloading good from the next code but images not. I get this files from Laravel Backend with an `return response()->download($full_path);`

The request in React is the next one:

```
export const getFileApi = async (token, documentType) => {
  const url = API_URL + `commerces/getFileDoc`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({document_type: documentType})
    });
    const data = await response.blob();
    console.log(data);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    link.download = documentType;
    link.click();
    if(data.errors) {
      return {
        error: data.errors
      }
    } else {
      return {
        data: data,
        error: null
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      error: JSON.stringify(error)
    }
  }
```

Console.log of data is printing this: [image]

When I open the image with Windows 10 the error says: "Seems that format of this file is not compatible"

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: In your request specify response type :blob

Comment: Looks like this in axios `axios.get(
    "url", { responseType: 'blob' })`

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif Hi, thanks for your response, I'm not using axios in my project, could be possible doing this without axios? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you made the request :D

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif Yes, I just edited the post with the full request :D

Comment: So the way i think it should be , you need to create a blob with the blob constructor , give it the data and provide it with the file type . this code is from my react app (it works perfectly) `const blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/zip' });`

Comment: I tried and error keeps persisting, anyway with the form i did it at start, the format.png it's good, it seems that is error of the content. I don't know if mby this can help. Thanks anyway for your time.